Pytest assert the original exception raised using `raise AnyException from MyExceptionToAssert`
I wrote a suit of tests that asserts exception (following what was said here How do I properly assert that an exception gets raised in pytest? and in the doc). However, there is one instance of my code where I need to raise an exception from the exception I want to assert.
How can I properly catch (and potentially match the message of) causing exceptions using pytest?
Here is a small reproducible code sample:
-- edit -- here is the code to test:
# in src/main.py

# this is not exactly like that in the code, but it is what s equivalent

class ModelValidationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *_):
        super().__init__(
            f"Unable to initialize model"
        )


class InvalidParametersWarning(Warning):
    def __init__(self, *_):
        super().__init__(
            "The given parameters are invalid"
        )

def handle_model_validation_error(environment: str, exception: ValueError):
    """Raise the correct exception based on the environment we are in.

    To avoid frightening the users, we raise a warning in production
    environments and an exception in development environments.

    Parameters
    ----------
    environment : str
        in which application environment we are in.
    exception : ValueError

    Raises
    ------
    ModelValidationError
        For development environments. Is is raised from the ValueError.
    InvalidParametersWarning
        For production environments.
    """
    if environment == "development":
        raise ModelValidationError() from exception
    else:
        raise InvalidParametersWarning()

import pytest

from src.main import handle_model_validation_error


def test_exception():
    # Here, I would like to match the message "nope" of ValueError
    # How can I do that?
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="nope"):
        handle_model_validation_error("development", ValueError("nope"))

-- end of edit --
which I think is equivalent to managing to match ValueError in:
import pytest


def test_exception():
    # Here, I would like to match the message "nope" of ValueError
    # How can I do that?
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="nope"):
        raise Exception from ValueError("nope")

Thank you for your time

Whats's the reason that your test needs to raise an exception and not the code you are testing ?

it's the code that I'm testing that raises the exception, but for the sake of minimal reproducible code, I wrote that

Please add the code to your question, which you want to test.

I just did :) thank you for your help

First of all, accessing the raised exception in the test is possible by assigning the pytest.raises context to a variable and then inspecting the value attribute. Example:
def spam():
    raise ValueError("eggs")

def test_spam():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as excinfo:
        spam()

    # excinfo.value is your exception instance now
    assert excinfo.value.args == ("eggs", )  # etc

Second, you can access a causing exception by inspecting the __context__ attribute. Example:
def spam():
    raise ValueError("eggs")

def eggs():
    try:
        spam()
    except ValueError as e:
        raise RuntimeError("bacon") from e


def test_eggs():
    with pytest.raises(RuntimeError) as excinfo:
        eggs()

    # excinfo.value is the RuntimeError now,
    assert excinfo.value.args == ("bacon", )
    # and excinfo.value.__context__ the ValueError
    assert excinfo.value.__context__.args == ("eggs", )

Now to your code in question. Intercepting a ValueError in
def test_exception():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="nope"):
        handle_model_validation_error()

is incorrect because handle_model_validation_error does not raise a ValueError. It raises a ModelValidationError, so you should expect this type as well.
Now, simply calling handle_model_validation_error() in
def test_exception():
    with pytest.raises(ModelValidationError):
        handle_model_validation_error()

will fail as handle_model_validation_error requires an exception instance as argument. This is a questionable design - you rarely need to work with exceptions as objects except when catching them. Therefore, in order to be able to call your function in the test, you need to create an exception instance. Simply doing something like
def test_exception():
    e = ValueError("spam")
    with pytest.raises(ModelValidationError):
        handle_model_validation_error(e)

will work, but e will be inaccessible in the exception context for further analysis since it was not raised anywhere.
Therefore, you would need to construct a try/except clause inside your test to actually put the ValueError in the exception context, like this:
def test_exception():
    main.model_parameters = "spam"  # as you didn't define it anywhere in your code
    causing_error = ValueError("eggs")
    with pytest.raises(main.ModelValidationError) as excinfo:
        try:
            raise causing_error
        except ValueError as e:
            main.handle_model_validation_error(e)

    # now you can inspect the ValueError
    assert causing_error == excinfo.value.__context__


Hello ! Thank you so much for your answer. I don't think I was super clear in my question. I do want to assert ValueError, but I just did not know how to do so. I wrote a close enough code sample to show that I knew how to use pytest along with exceptions, in the hope of orienting a solution towards deeper (possibly undocumented) use of the library.

Anywho, accessing the causing exception with excinfo.value.__context__ seems to be the solution. I'm gonna do the match myself using regex. I'm also gonna open a feature request on pytest github to be able to catch and match causing exceptions.

You should pass environment to handle_model_validation_error, you dont want to test global state:
import unittest
import pytest


class ModelValidationError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *_):
        super().__init__(
            f"Unable to initialize model"
        )


class InvalidParametersWarning(Warning):
    def __init__(self, *_):
        super().__init__(
            "The given parameters are invalid"
        )

def handle_model_validation_error(environment: str, exception: ValueError):
    """Raise the correct exception based on the environment we are in.

    To avoid frightening the users, we raise a warning in production
    environments and an exception in development environments.

    Parameters
    ----------
    exception : ValueError

    Raises
    ------
    ModelValidationError
        For development environments. Is is raised from the ValueError.
    InvalidParametersWarning
        For production environments.
    """
    model_parameters = {}
    if environment == "development":
        raise ModelValidationError(model_parameters) from exception
    else:
        raise InvalidParametersWarning(model_parameters)


class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_handle_ModelValidationError(self):
        with pytest.raises(ModelValidationError) as excinfo:  
            handle_model_validation_error("development", ValueError)
        self.assertEqual(str(excinfo.value) , "Unable to initialize model")
 
    def test_handle_InvalidParametersWarning(self):
        with pytest.raises(InvalidParametersWarning) as excinfo:  
            handle_model_validation_error("production", ValueError)
        self.assertEqual(str(excinfo.value) , "The given parameters are invalid")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Out:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK


Hello, thank you for your answer. I cleaned up my question with your suggestion of passing environment as a variable. In my code, I created a proxy function that fetches the real environment variable and passes everything to handle_model_validation_error (which is tested).

As for your answer, it does not match the right error. My goal is to match the ValueError and its message. ValueError only exists as a causing exception in "development" environment. See @Hoefling solution of using exception.value.__context__

I ended up mocking my environment variable as it was simpler to do.

thanks to @hoefling's answer, I've been able to achieve what I wanted with a workaround.
I created the associated feature request on pytest's github.
def spam():
    raise ValueError("spam")

def eggs():
    try:
        spam()
    except ValueError as e:
        raise RuntimeError("eggs") from e

def test_catch_cause_exception():
    # match any exception
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as exc:
        eggs()

    # match the cause exception
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="spam"):
        # in case the first exception caught does not have a cause.
        # This will mark the test as failed with `did not raise`.
        if exc.value.__cause__ is not None:
            raise exc.value.__cause__

If you replace __cause__ with __context__, you can also catch context errors.
